# Square Brackets after wb.DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, brackets

I'm doing a udemy course on Python and I  stumbled upon this line of code that I couldn't quite comprehend.

```
mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1995-1-1')['Adj Close']
```

What do the Square Brackets containing 'Adj Close' do?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you type in `type(wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1995-1-1')` you will get a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as the output. An example

```
my_dict = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
print my_dict['jack']
```

This will return the output `4098`, the value for the key `'jack'` given in `my_dict`